# Segue called twice - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viper-architecture

I am using from `VIP` in my project and when I route user to another scene open the scene twice ,my router is like bellow? if your need more detail say me. Thank's

```
@objc protocol ListLanguageRoutingLogic
{
    func routeToStartPage(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?)
}

protocol LangSelectedDataPassing
{
    var dataStore: SelectLanguageDataStore? { get }
}

class RouterSelectLanguage: NSObject, ListLanguageRoutingLogic, LangSelectedDataPassing
{
    weak var viewControllerSelectLanguage: ViewControllerSelectLanguage?
    var dataStore: SelectLanguageDataStore?
    func routeToStartPage(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?) {
        print("BBB")
        let destinationVC = viewControllerSelectLanguage?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerStartPage") as! ViewControllerStartPage
        var destinationDS = destinationVC.router!.dataStore!
        passDataToStartPage(source: dataStore!, destination: &destinationDS)
        navigateToStartPage(source: viewControllerSelectLanguage!, destination: destinationVC)
    }

    // MARK: Navigation
    func navigateToStartPage(source: ViewControllerSelectLanguage, destination: ViewControllerStartPage)
    {
        source.show(destination, sender: nil)
    }
    // MARK: Passing data
    func passDataToStartPage(source: SelectLanguageDataStore, destination: inout StartPageDataStore)
    {
        print("CCC")
        let selectedRow = viewControllerSelectLanguage?.tblView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
        destination.langSelected = source.langs?[selectedRow!]
    }
}
```

And:

[image]

Comment: I added .show in func navigateToStartPage... .

Comment: @ Mohmmad S. Look at my source code more carefully please.

Comment: @ Mohmmad S. .show is a method for IOS 12.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved my problem, I edited my source code like bellow and good work now:

```
@objc protocol ListLanguageRoutingLogic
{
    func routeToStartPage(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?)
}

protocol LangSelectedDataPassing
{
    var dataStore: SelectLanguageDataStore? { get }
}

class RouterSelectLanguage: NSObject, ListLanguageRoutingLogic, LangSelectedDataPassing
{
    weak var viewControllerSL: ViewControllerSelectLanguage?
    var dataStore: SelectLanguageDataStore?
    func routeToStartPage(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?) {
        let destinationVC = segue!.destination as! ViewControllerStartPage
        var destinationDS = destinationVC.startPageRouter!.dataStore!
        passDataToStartPage(source: dataStore!, destination: &destinationDS)

    }

    // MARK: Passing data
    func passDataToStartPage(source: SelectLanguageDataStore, destination: inout StartPageDataStore)
    {
        let selectedRow = viewControllerSL?.tblView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
        destination.langSelected = source.langs?[selectedRow!]
    }
}
```